# CSS issues in ROR

Tags: css, ruby

I'm learning an online ROR course and I encountered some problems with the CSS. I am not sure how CSS formatting works in ruby together with CSS. Am I doing it correctly?

[image: Code]

However, when I run my app, this screen appears. 
[image: Website view]

Did I make an error somewhere? Or is this the wrong way to type my CSS in rails?

Comment: You are closing the style tag after the head tag. It seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you should use this structure and make sure that you are closing tags in correct order:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
<style>
</style>
    </head>

    <body>
    The content of the document......
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, may be it will work

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Alpha-Blog</h1>

<head>

  <style>
    .img-class{
        display: block;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<%= link_to image_tag(''), class: "img-class" %>

<%= link_to "About", about_path %>
```